# How can I view a backup (.bkf) file from XP

Tags: windows-xp, backup

I need to confirm the modified dates on curtain files to confirm that the backup is working correctly.

Is there a tool that allows you to view the contents of a backup file other then the windows backup utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could download systools-ms backup recovery software-it has a trial period and will let you see in side a system backup that does not open with the normal ms backup and restore,up to you-the free ones should also let you see in side, you dont have to restore.
edit-they have the-ntbackup restore utilities-at microsoft xp help this the microsoft fix and will for free open and restore all data,etc.

Comment: seems like the best chance

Answer (score 0):

Most of the recovery software for BKF files allow you to extract the contents, then you could verify dates.

Comment: I figured as much but they all cost money, the edit kinda explains that...